# Authorization google OAuth 2.0 on the server side, how to check the token?

Tags: javascript, php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I can not verify the user token ID on the server side. Did on the guide from Google
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

In JS I get the id token and send it to the server

```js
var googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get(),
    id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://api.site.loc//tokensignin');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
```

I accept on the server

```php
$CLIENT_ID = '.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$id_token = $formData['idtoken'];

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
   $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

as a result I get this error, instead of confirming token

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'id_token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken' in \google-api-php-client\src\Google\Client.php:717
```

Comment: You either have no token (null) or you have the wrong token (there are three different types).

Comment: Really, thanks. Fixed now everything works

Comment: Post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to the fact that `$id_token` was empty (null).
So if you have such a problem, check that the `$id_token` is correct

Thanks to John Hanley for the help